# ZTE Nubia Z5 Problem?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, bootloader

I have a Zte Nubia Z5 ("2nd Hand") with a software camera problem (I think is a software problem because the camera works sometimes)

The phone has Android 4.1.2. I tried to hard reset the phone but I just got a white screen. And I tried to enter into Recovery Mode and get the same white screen. The phone in `adb devices` is recognized as "NX501 Recovery". Normally is in "NX501 Device". That means something in the Recovery NAND or something I do not know is bad.

The phone was normally working fine, since my brother installed Chainfire 3D and is stuck in the boot logo, a normal tune is heard as normal like its entering in the OS. But still stuck on the boot logo. I read that is a Chainfire 3D problem in some devices.

So I start to try To install some custom recovery CWM, TWRP etc. It was difficult to find a Recovery because all the information you can find on the internet about this phone is in Chinese and Russian.

I did find a TWRP Recovery (Also a CWM too), but both in Chinese. I tried to enter in boot-loader mode to install the custom Recovery. The phone does go into the the boot-loader and gets recognized as a "Sooner ADB Device", but in ADB does not get recognized. With ANY of the ADB Drivers, ADB Composite, ADB Interface etc.!

Comment: try `sudo fastboot flash recovery openrecovery-twrp-x.x.x.img` or `sudo flash recovery recovery-clockwork-x.x.x.img`?

Comment: @t0mm13b Nothing Happend!